# displaying horizontal cards then user selects one [click event] & open another modal and display data from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am displaying cards horizontally on the screen. Each card a user can click on it, it rotates to the back side of the card and a button is there [click on it] to display information from mysql database, but it does not work.

I have not been able to find a solution.  Tried using JavaScript to pass the information, but did not work.

```
  <script>
     function BusinessAdd($Bname) {
        document.getElementById('BusName').value = $Bname  
        reference:  //$row['BusinessName'];
     }
  </script>



    <!-- Horizontally scroll the cards 
    **************************************************************** -->
    <!-- read fabcustomerdata Table-->
    <?php include "ReadFabCustomerTable.php"; ?>

    <div class="middlecontainer">
      <div class="row">

        <?php

            //$query="SELECT * FROM fabcustomerdata";
             $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                if(!$result) {
                    die('Query FAILED' . mysqli_error($connection));
                }

            // - pull thru the Table 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            ?>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <div class="flip-card"                             
                      onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover')">
                    <div class="flip-card-inner">
                         <div class="flip-card-front">
                              <img class='winpane' src="Vend-images/<? 
                                 php echo $row["WindowPane"]; ?>" alt=""/>
                         </div>
                         <div class="flip-card-back">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" 
                id="<?php echo $row["checkboxid"];?>"                        
                onclick="myChkBoxFunction('<?php echo $row["checkboxid"];
                ?>')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" 
                title="Check Box to save this Card" />

                <?php
                   echo '<address>';
                   echo '<br />';
                   echo "<b style='font- 
                         size:1.2rem'>".$row['BusinessName']."</b>";
                   echo "<br /><br />";
                   echo $row['OfficeAddress']."<br>";
                   echo $row['OfficeCity'].",".$row['OfficeState']." 
                      ".$row['OfficePostalCode']."<br />";
                   echo $row['OfficePhNo'];
                   echo '</address>';

                   echo "<a href=".$row['website'].">
                         <h5>Official Website</h5></a>";?>
                ?>                          

              <span onclick='BusinessAdd("<?php echo 
               $row['BusinessAddress']; ?>")' type="button" data- 
               toggle="modal" data-target="#Business-Signup" data- 
               backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"> Business 
               Information</span>

              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <?php
        }
     ?>

     <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to 
       top">Top</button>

    </div>
</div>


 <!-- *********** fill out Business information ********************* -->
  <form id="BusinessInformation" >  <!-- action="" method="post" -->
     <div class="modal animate fade" id="Business-Signup" role="dialog" 
         aria-labelledby="CenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="CenterTitle"> 
                         <strong>Business Information:</strong></h5>
                    <div class="SiteViews">
                        <label style="color: #0f4471;" class="buslabel" 
                           for="Views">Views: </label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
                          aria-label="Close">
                        <span style="margin-right: 25px;" aria- 
                            hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="CompanyInfo">
                        <ul>
                        <li>
               <br /><label class="buslabel" for="Name">Business Name: 
               <strong><input id="BusName" value="<?php echo 
                   $row['BusinessName']; ?>" type="text" tabindex="1" 
                    class="businput search" placeholder="Business Name" 
                      size="30" name="Business Name" max="30" required> 
               </strong>
               </label>
```

Need to be able to click on the button [on back of the card] and open another modal to display data from mysql database about that card.

Need to somehow link the card so that it is associated with the item in the database for that particular card.

Comment: You should separate your PHP, JavaScript and HTML from each other. This is very difficult to read.

Comment: Adding to what @Dharman saidm why in the middle are you `echo`ing address/br tags via PHP and not just outputting them?

Comment: @Dharman I will edit it to see if I can make it clearer..

Comment: @Dharman OK, I cleaned it up best I could...  Hope this makes it easier to review.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused  Humm, not sure how that would work?

Comment: @JRse Where is the JS though? I see a call to `myChkBoxFunction` and `topFunction` but I don't see their code.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused all that does is provide a checkbox to save the card on the screen.  But I have not yet set that to the database..  TopFunction is there so that when there are many cards that scroll down the screen [cards are horizontally displayed [6 each] and then it goes down vertically the height of a card plus space between them] and display's another row of 6 cards and repeats for as many as there are needed.   So you can scroll down to to the bottom & the you just click the topFunction and it takes you back to the top of the page.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused I originally tried to use javascript to pass the Business Name to then do a query and read the database, but it never worked.    Here it is:    //<script>
function BusinessAdd($Bname) {
   document.getElementById('BusName').value = $Bname // 
  refrence:  $row['BusinessName'];
}
//</script>                                       and tried to use it for the button click as follows:           <span onclick='BusinessAdd("<?php echo $row['BusinessAddress']; ?>");

Comment: @JRse Can you edit the question and add your code.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused I added the script code, is there something else I need to add?

Comment: @dazed-and-confused ok I added another piece of the puzzle so you can see where the clicking of the "Button" opens another modal where I can't get the data to flow.

Comment: @JRse There are a lot of problems here. It looks like you're using PHP variables in your JS. You're doing `document.getElementById('BusName')` but there aren't any elements with BusName declared. Based on what I'm seeing, this might be above your level. Try to break down this problem into smaller ones because there's lots of parts here.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused at the bottom of the code [where I added more code], you can see the id="BusName", so by reference.

Comment: @jrse Again, I would just break this all down into much smaller steps. Start by building out a simple HTML page that does the action you need on just one card. Once you have some basic functionality, start adding the other parts.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused That's a great suggestion, Thanks for your review/advice..